# Failed to make a request to https://storage.googleapis.com

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy the default test function provided when I first enable firebase functions in my project  and I am getting an error which is persistent.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

These are the versions of my softwares installed below
node: v18.17.0 (Even when I install the latest version of node, the error is persistent)

"firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
"firebase-tools": 13.4.0
"npm":10.4.0
"node": v18.17.0

**here is my firebase.json file**

```
  {
     "functions": [
       {
         "source": "functions",
         "codebase": "default",
         "ignore": [
           "node_modules",
           ".git",
           "firebase-debug.log",
          "firebase-debug.*.log"
          ],
        
           //Even when I remove this part (predeploy) the error keeps showing
          "predeploy": [
           "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
         ] 
       }
     ]
   }
```

**Here is the Package.json file**

```
    {
      "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^8.57.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "firebase-functions": "^4.7.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "lint": "eslint ."
      }
    
    }
```

I'm trying deploy functions using only:
**firebase deploy --only functions**

=== Deploying to 'revival-academy'...

```
    i  deploying functions               
    i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...         
    i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...             
    i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
    +  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
    i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
    Serving at port 8844
    
    i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
    i  functions: packaged C:\src\StudioProjects\Revival_academies\creche\functions (74.18 KB) for uploading
    i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
    i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
    i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
    i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
    +  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
    +  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
    i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
    i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
    24c.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-372042583890%40gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1709026786&Signature=JfBwxH%2BIfbth7FfVGpUUKLC%2FXgoOscYD153RtpZ
    V2zLLpq1lH4%2FZEsD7hJn7s3SI0YxHN41NAWdZ0O6tzpEKBMse%2B7s%2FFkLxhlKIP4YJL9%2F6BAEzKYabew5IXL%2FzrQhALT%2B%2FxuahbJrKlB%2FJwRioaOoMIy8ay6r2DU1gEzY%2BwoCh9snoa%2
    
    Error: Failed to make request to https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-v2-uploads-372042583890-us-central1/3a8f57d9-815f-4959-94a4-b856fe06524c.zip?GoogleAccessI
    d=service-372042583890%40gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1709026786&Signature=JfBwxH%2BIfbth7FfVGpUUKLC%2FXgoOscYD153RtpZCNiwpaZQJ838LMXFagkLf
    7crUQ0KsBKOp315T8OkMobIkFS6WsqgeXk3CqflqH1%2BNoktwhNOg097gQxVJbTPJiDESMuZI6iu3r90xWLvozblce6N5OkHnUbzbYCCo3x0NeuaCpYGO%2F3tUiLp%2FjgwMxKbV2zLLpq1lH4%2FZEsD7hJ
    n7s3SI0YxHN41NAWdZ0O6tzpEKBMse%2B7s%2FFkLxhlKIP4YJL9%2F6BAEzKYabew5IXL%2FzrQhALT%2B%2FxuahbJrKlB%2FJwRioaOoMIy8ay6r2DU1gEzY%2BwoCh9snoa%2B0Dw2Q8oihoAQ%3D%3D
```

**When I run firebase functions:log, this is what I am getting**

```json
2024-02-26T09:09:39.997131Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mygmailaccount@
    gmail.com","principalSubject":"user:mygmailaccount@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"41.116.70.216","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/13.3.1,
    gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2024-02-26T09:09:50.029165Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis
    .com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeSet","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{},"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"}],"resourceName":"proje
    cts/revival-academy/locations/us-central1","request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlRequest","parent":"projects/revi
    val-academy/locations/us-central1"},"response":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlResponse","uploadUrl":"https://storage
    .googleapis.com/uploads-912355258456.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/c3b23a83-e243-4a26-a87b-7842da5131ee.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-372042583890@gcf-a
    dmin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1708940389&Signature=WwYbBXHMpzn%2B5alLVKmmJ8MeoiQgSUJIZWHWvWE2ZLuUHaVDgHlm7vtb7sT9pZ2%2BKL72Ukyp11to5dKkWBLDdPqTdk
    Lifw0f0u9qBqaoXvmUTdLMTwqG4HafE70rKMvoEmhuaXeOVicVwFg7CZ%2F28XpEfEi4cW5tod4UxjAUoDqUWQ6l%2FoR9Y1Ax0LErWZKoIPMDGtxfDcTeOnQJG5gFnSowkuqXzeAfosuOdWe8AySUf%2Fli%2
    F0Zs0EDZV3lAjxQUxhbjpiGOaxjx3ub0kNRNhKkdqUMTZWxFFPFHcCsg2%2B7ABom9%2BEn7Z4jazitDehhLlMS0F5SLtBYqG%2BGbywYRjQ%3D%3D"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["
    us-central1"]}}
    2024-02-26T09:09:49.969070Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{},"serviceName":"cloudfu
    nctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","resourceName":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1"}
    2024-02-26T10:24:16.848004Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mygmailaccount@
    gmail.com","principalSubject":"user:mygmailaccount@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"41.116.70.216","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/13.3.1,
    gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2024-02-26T10:24:17.401683Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis
    .com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeSet","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{},"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"}],"resourceName":"proje
    cts/revival-academy/locations/us-central1","request":{"parent":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us-central1","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.func
    tions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlRequest"},"response":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlResponse","uploadUrl":"https://storage
    .googleapis.com/uploads-912355258456.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/ef7bec94-6892-45e1-9eec-94117d87c6d5.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-372042583890@gcf-a
    dmin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1708944857&Signature=EVnYh7DbBzLp4lVFp%2BDMFeTT7LZhpEPyrWRxIjAfWNmlpCD4yuF9rDvqbVnMHcu0PRAlYi0Vq2UDKA%2F6IAOQpOXKxS
    hCP3EN53v6fbgUK9WpsBqW1h8L12wGHmYltubugp5p5xogpj4FzF3F254UsocwyirqhkJekgauD27aqNd5k5dIUsfVEf3K080la1IbfPGdaVg2KIskmDl%2FcixKJ7ejZJOWjbOpQ5KmX%2FDcYdJLAXCrwTdZ
    CorjCe%2FIS%2FPwXPomvogWX83JeQXSqgcX1MYxtwmZB7MPoiWvAfg2P6xPmVqSsqF7%2BYbmVjs3vmsSYoY00tfoS5Mawl3EBJJSFg%3D%3D"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-c
    entral1"]}}
    2024-02-26T10:24:17.339854Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{},"serviceName":"cloudfu
    nctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","resourceName":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1"}
    2024-02-26T10:49:45.922920Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mygmailaccount@
    gmail.com","principalSubject":"user:mygmailaccount@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"41.116.70.216","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/13.3.1,
    gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2024-02-26T10:49:46.453098Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis
    .com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeSet","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{},"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"}],"resourceName":"proje
    cts/revival-academy/locations/us-central1","request":{"parent":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us-central1","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.func
    tions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlRequest"},"response":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.GenerateUploadUrlResponse","uploadUrl":"https://storage
    .googleapis.com/uploads-912355258456.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/34727eaa-ef53-47e6-874b-43d816936e61.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-372042583890@gcf-a
    dmin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1708946386&Signature=rQvCv9G58vFhTe86pRX%2B0kMS9RlzyuZtkBmPYcFwxIiNfndaLvaI7WknqKHYJ57oqHop%2BOxE%2Fs1OmYdK8PrReJIz
    YMG7jXtbrvSFZvPAu8ctMP7ekH8o1nrC5eLknnx8hLVEFZfbAOuoLH0%2FJgleqgMymTkRpa%2BXuzARqzns%2BZvEXHdMiurhxKoBZ7XnGA2hJx%2BNRfYgxBElVH7xiBE0T2%2Fp5VFdsJmnNgugo%2BkHn0
    nJ%2FZUpWUuTHePoF3UNQc6pT01caA1MT3n189%2FybDkXU8IydrDTM0oZIquckcJkvi5bRI7iwieK2MM4L5YxBBNH8j%2FZznZl3vd715pCdjmVJg%3D%3D"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocatio
    ns":["us-central1"]}}
    2024-02-26T10:49:46.393437Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{},"serviceName":"cloudfu
    nctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.GenerateUploadUrl","resourceName":"projects/revival-academy/locations/us
    -central1"}
```

I tried reinstalling the firebase tools, node, and reauthenticated my account, I also ran npm run lint and tried deploying a different function after recreating the function folder.

Comment: Can you try to update your [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/cli#version_1331_-_february_21_2024) to the latest version and redeploy by adding this `firebase --debug --only functions deploy` to your code? Also have a look at this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73298790/18265702) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66456400/18265702).

Comment: I updated the Firebase CLI to the latest version and ran the deployment command like you suggested yet I still get the same error.

Error: Failed to make request to https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-912355258456.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/...

Comment: I have tried with the default [firebase.json](https://codefile.io/f/qxyukU5sfC) and [package.json](https://codefile.io/f/bU0O9ckESb) files by disabling the `eslint: ^8.57.0` and deployed successfully without any errors. Seems like you missed adding the `storage rules` in the `package.json` file.

Comment: Also I can see your `firebase-admin` version is: “^7.0.0” Can you try updating it to `"firebase-admin": "^11.8.0"`. Make sure the installed packages are compatible with the Node version.

Comment: Okay I also tried what you asked me to implement and still I got the same error.
I also sent an email to verify if this issue is with my account or somethings else is going on.

Comment: Can you share the `storage.rules` file?

Comment: Alright, [storage.rules](https://codefile.io/f/yCxwEpk6Bn)

Comment: Still no luck for the same issue :(

Comment: yes I am still facing the same issue. google support suggested these below

THe cause off the deployment falure is this >>> ECONNRESET

In order to verify this, I would recommend performing the following:

1. Try connecting to a different network.
2. Temporarily turn off any proxy, firewall or VPN that you may have.
3. Try deploying the function with a different computer.

I am in that process of testing these steps as we speak but it doesn't make sense because I can deploy an empty index.js file and it succeeds, I dont see how the network could be the issue, but ill keep trying

Comment: Here is the solution to the issue

I changed the device I was using to access the internet from then I tried to deploy the function and it worked with no issues. encountered.

For instance, I am using my phone to hotspot my laptop as I code, so I only used another phone to hospot the same laptop.

I still don't get why the issue is persistant with my main phone because both my phone and laptop dont have APN configure or proxy enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the device I use to access my internet connection did the trick.